# Select row when a selectOneMenu changes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I change the value of the `selectOneMenu` I need to set the row in the backing bean and update a button which is in the same row.

```
<p:dataTable
    id="dataTableId" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowKey="#{record.id}"
    rows="10" selection="#{bean.selectedRecord}" selectionMode="single"
    value="#{bean.allRecords}" var="record" widgetVar="dataTableWV">

    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
            id="selectOnMenuId" value="#{bean.recordDTO}">
            <f:selectItems
                itemLabel="#{status.name}" itemValue="#{status.id}" value="#{bean.statusList}" var="status" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="saveButtonId">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedRecord}" value="#{record}" />
            </p:ajax>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton action="#{bean.someMethod}" icon="ui-icon-disk" id="saveButtonId" update="someId"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Edit @Tiny suggestions:**

```
<p:dataTable
    id="dataTableId" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowKey="#{record.id}"
    rows="10" selection="#{bean.selectedRecord}" selectionMode="single"
    value="#{bean.allRecords}" var="record" widgetVar="dataTableWV">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
        listener="#{bean.anotherMethod(record)}"
        update="somesIds" />

    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
            id="selectOnMenuId" value="#{bean.recordDTO}">
            <f:selectItems
                itemLabel="#{status.name}" itemValue="#{status.id}" value="#{bean.statusList}" var="status" />
            <p:ajax event="change"
                listener="#{bean.anotherMethod(record)}"
                update="saveButtonId" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton action="#{bean.someMethod}" icon="ui-icon-disk" id="saveButtonId" update="someId"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Please describe the culprit, if any. I would avoid using an `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` in this way. I would rather use `<p:ajax listener=#{bean.listener(record)} .../>` with a parameterized method (EL 2.2).

Comment: Yes…  and? This does not work? But what does happen? You can (should) do a lot of debugging yourself. Monitor ajax calls check scopes etc…

Comment: @Tiny I made some edits in my question. In rowSelect event the record is null but in the selectOneMenu it works great

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't get any ajax error. It seems as the setPropertyActionListener doesn't work

Comment: So, what did you get at the end of the story? I hope, the last appended code snippet should be working as expected now.

Comment: I get a null value as a record value an then a NullPointerException